# Stop loop from duplicating content

Tags: php, sql, foreach, wordpress

There's a loop in a wordpress plugin that I'm trying to modify.

```
$dataarray = explode(',',$data);
foreach ($dataarray as $entry){
    $sql .= "OR ID = '$entry' ";
}   

$endvar = wp_parse_args( $var, $defaults );
extract( $endvar, EXTR_SKIP );
$sql = preg_replace("/^OR./","", $sql); 
$order = $endvar['order_by'];
$my_posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name2 WHERE $sql ORDER BY $order");
$mod_url = mfp_create_link_url();

foreach ($my_posts as $entry){
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($entry->ID, 'thumbnail');
    $fav_post .= $entry_before."<a href='".get_permalink($entry->ID)."' title='".$entry->post_title."' class='".$endvar['link_class']."'>".$entry->post_title."</a>".$entry_after;
    echo $fav_post;
    echo pippin_excerpt_by_id($entry);
}
```

This displays;

```
<thumbnail-1>
   <title-1>
     <excerpt-1>
<thumbnail-2>
   **<title-1>**
   <title-2>
     <excerpt-2>
```

I can't figure out why it displays `<title-1>` two times while the others are displayed only one time.

Comment: Better to post the actual resulting HTML than pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within your loop you're appending

```
$fav_post .=
```

then echoing

```
echo $fav_post;
```

Never setting it to blank within the loop. Remove the period or just echo the line

```
echo $entry_before."<a href='"...
```